# В PHPStorm не прокликиваются мои методы и часть методов фреймворка

Tags: phpstorm

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сам код работает без замечаний, раздражает только невозможность кликнуть по методу и попасть в него.

Содержимое RequstModel:

```
/**
 * @var RequestModel
 */

class RequestModel extends CI_Model
{
    public $id;
    ...
```

Часть классов и методов используемого фреймворка тоже не прокликиваются, что наводит на мысль, что что-то не настроено в PHPStorm.

C другой стороны если в фреймворке отключить автозагрузку моделей и создать экземпляр класса, то прокликиваться будет, но приложение выдаст "Class "RequestModel" not found":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось что Шторм не при чем. Некоторые фреймворки настолько "фрейм", что просто "ворк" не получается.
Правильный ход был:

*"отключить автозагрузку моделей средствами фреймворка и создать экземпляр класса".*

Но создавать его не в конструкторе, а непосредсвенно перед работой с моделью. Тогда и с точки зрения и IDE и вашего приложения все будет правильно.